# expanding \ref in \write with \classicthesis

Tags: expansion, classicthesis

The following code:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
% \usepackage{classicthesis}

\newwrite\myauxfile
\immediate\openout\myauxfile=test.myaux

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  This is a figure
  \caption{This is a caption}
  \label{fig:1}
\end{figure}
Figure~\ref{fig:1}
\write\myauxfile{Figure \ref{fig:1}}
\end{document}
```

produces a file `test.myaux` containing the following line:

```
Figure \relax 0.1\hbox {}
```

If I include the `classicthesis` package (uncommenting the second line) The reference number is not expanded and the file `test.myaux` contains the following line:

```
Figure \ref  {fig:1}
```

which is not what I want. Is it possible to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you want to use `\getrefnumber`:

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{classicthesis}
\usepackage{refcount}

\newwrite\myauxfile
\immediate\openout\myauxfile=\jobname.myaux

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  This is a figure
  \caption{This is a caption}
  \label{fig:1}
\end{figure}
Figure~\ref{fig:1}
\write\myauxfile{Figure \getrefnumber{fig:1}}
\end{document}
```

The new aux file will contain

```
Figure 1
```

Comment: yes, this is even better!